# Where are the symbols etext, edata and end defined?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ld

This is a code from Linux man page:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern char etext, edata, end;

int main() {
    printf("First address past:\n");
    printf("    program text (etext)      %10p\n", &etext);
    printf("    initialized data (edata)  %10p\n", &edata);
    printf("    uninitialized data (end)  %10p\n", &end);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

when run, the program below produces output such as the following:

```
$ ./a.out
First address past:
    program text (etext)       0x8048568
    initialized data (edata)   0x804a01c
    uninitialized data (end)   0x804a024
```

Where are `etext`, `edata` `end` defined ? How those symbols are assigned values ? Is it by linker or something else ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These symbols are defined in a [linker script file](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Using_ld_the_GNU_Linker/scripts.html) (dead link copy [at archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20191019064820/https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Using_ld_the_GNU_Linker/scripts.html)).

Comment: The link 404s :/

Answer (score 14):

Note that on Mac OS X, the code above may not work! Instead you can have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mach-o/getsect.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("    program text (etext)      %10p\n", (void*)get_etext());
    printf("    initialized data (edata)  %10p\n", (void*)get_edata());
    printf("    uninitialized data (end)  %10p\n", (void*)get_end());

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

**What GCC does**

Expanding [kgiannakakis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1766000/895245) a bit more.

Those symbols are defined by the `PROVIDE` keyword of the linker script, documented at https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.25/ld/PROVIDE.html#PROVIDE

The default scripts are generated when you build Binutils, and embedded into the `ld` executable: external files that may be installed in your distribution like in `/usr/lib/ldscripts` are not used by default.

Echo the linker script to be used:

```
ld -verbose | less
```

In binutils 2.24 it contains:

```
.text           :
{
  *(.text.unlikely .text.*_unlikely .text.unlikely.*)
  *(.text.exit .text.exit.*)
  *(.text.startup .text.startup.*)
  *(.text.hot .text.hot.*)
  *(.text .stub .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)
  /* .gnu.warning sections are handled specially by elf32.em.  */
  *(.gnu.warning)
}
.fini           :
{
  KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.fini)))
}
PROVIDE (__etext = .);
PROVIDE (_etext = .);
PROVIDE (etext = .);
.rodata         : { *(.rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.*) }
.rodata1        : { *(.rodata1) }
```

So we also discover that:

- `__etext` and `_etext` will also work
- `etext` is not the end of the `.text` section, but rather `.fini`, which also contains code
- `etext` is not at the end of the segment, with `.rodata` following it, since Binutils dumps all readonly sections into the same segment

`PROVIDE` generates weak symbols: if you also define those symbols in your C code, your definition will win and hide this one.

**Minimal Linux 32-bit example**

To truly understand how things work, I like to create minimal examples!

`main.S`:

```
.section .text
    /* Exit system call. */
    mov $1, %eax
    /* Exit status. */
    mov sdata, %ebx
    int $0x80
.section .data
    .byte 2
```

`link.ld`:

```
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x400000;
    .text :
    {
        *(.text)
        sdata = .;
        *(.data)
    }
}
```

Compile and run:

```
gas --32 -o main.o main.S
ld -m elf_i386 -o main -T link.ld main.o
./main
echo $?
```

Output:

```
 2
```

Explanation: `sdata` points to the first byte of the start of the `.data` section that follows.

So by controlling the first byte of that section, we control the exit status!

[This example on GitHub](https://github.com/cirosantilli/assembly-cheat/blob/d60f55ed7dcf54dd7083a2d4fdcfd6b79b15c084/linker-scripts/edata.ld#L5).

Answer (score 3):

Those symbols correspond to the beginnings of various program segments.  They are set by the linker.