# AT32UC3/WinAVR const variable at fixed address

Tags: avr, avr-gcc, winavr

I'm using a AT32UC3B0256 microcontroller in combination with AVR32Studio 2.6 and I wouuld like to please a constant variable at a fixed address (
e.g. at position 0x80799999) at the end of the flash.

```
const int variable __attribute__((section(????))) = 1234;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to place a variable at a given absolute address in memory (with GCC)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067811/how-to-place-a-variable-at-a-given-absolute-address-in-memory-with-gcc)

Answer (score 1):

In Program use

```
const int variable __attribute__((section(".varaddress"))) = 1234;
```

and in your linker script add this flag:

```
-wl,--section-start=.varaddress=0x80799999
```

Also you can check [Memory Sections](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/mem_sections.html) in AVR