# What is the equivalent of Keil _at_ in gcc

Tags: c, gcc, keil

Does gcc have any keyword exactly equivalent to `_at_` in [Keil](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_ap_at.htm)?

```
struct Location
{
  uint_32 x;
  uint_32 y;
  uint_32 z;
  char protocol[10];
};

struct link idata list _at_ 0x40;     /* list at idata 0x40 */
```

Note: I do not want to define a pointer at all. I want an exactly the same variable.

Note: the `idata` here can be ignored.

Comment: Which target platform do you use?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067811/how-to-place-a-variable-at-a-given-absolute-address-in-memory-with-gcc

Comment: What is `link`? What has `Location` anything to do with the rest?

Comment: @Acorn, It is a hypothetical example. In reality, the structure holds information to be sent to a server host including an encryption buffer. This data is supposed to be read by the embedded OS and then dispatched. That's why the application has such an obligation.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't. This Keil support [page](http://www.keil.com/support/docs/2829.htm) on the topic also suggests there is no direct equivalent of CARM's `__at__` and armcc's `__attribute__(at)` in gcc:

```
GNU GCC Compiler
Use only pointer definitions to access absolute memory locations. For example:

/* General Purpose Input/Output (GPIO) */
#define IOPIN0         (*((volatile unsigned long *) 0xE0028000))
.
.
.
IOPIN0 = 0x4;
```

As an alternative to that, you can also define your own sections using an `ld` script.

Comment: Then how do you guarantee that your variable does not collide with another variable?
Forget windows and Linux. If you have an embedded system OS which reads certain address locations in the application to communicate, then your application cannot have a clean design but it should follow the OS rules. Yet, I need to have my struct defined in the designated address.

Comment: Please forget my original `struct` example. It was a copy/paste without much evaluation. I have updated it to a better one.

Comment: I guess such a collision may only be possible if the memory section your variable resides in is used by the compiler (e.g. somewhere in .data). But you could guarantee that the compiler won't interfere by scripting it in the linker, maybe use a dedicated section for that.

Comment: Thank you very much. Would you please explain it in more details how to do that?

Comment: You probably need something like this adapted for your board: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/438488/gcc-attribute-section-not-working