# What is the use of the SHT_NULL section in ELF?

Tags: elf

1. What is the purpose of the `SHT_NULL` section in `ELF`?
2. Is it referenced by the OS or the loader?
3. What is the size of this section?
4. Does it have anything to do with the *NULL* pointer ?
5. Additionally, why does this section not have an entry in the section-segments mapping?

**From the ELF specification:**

*`SHT_NULL` : This value marks the section header as inactive; it does not have an associated section. Other members of the section header have undefined values.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is the purpose of the SHT_NULL section in elf?

It serves as a [sentinel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value).

> Is it referenced by the operating system or the loader?

No.

> What is the size of this section ?

Zero (you can see that in `readelf -WS a.out` output) [but see below].

> why does this section not have an entry in the section-segments mapping ?

Because that section is not present in any segment.

---

Normally, the very first section in every ELF file is of type `SHT_NULL`. In theory, a post-link tool may set the type of *some other* section to `SHT_NULL` as well (e.g. if its data is no longer needed), and all subsequent tools are supposed to ignore that section. This is not common.

Comment: It seems the SHT_NULL section has no real purpose in the process' image. Is there any part of the elf that can be used to indicate to the OS to reserve a non-allocatable and non RWX area in memory to handle NULL pointer exceptions ?

Comment: @daemon155 I don't understand what you mean by "to handle NULL pointer exceptions". It's likely best to ask a new question, and provide as much detail as you can.

Comment: Why is this sentinel required? Aren't all offsets / sizes well specified?

Comment: I don't think it has a real purpose or was required for something. My guess would be that it was rather defined by the ELF standart to be the first entry, maybe they wanted to have a "dummy section and section header"

Answer (score 8):

One "use" of `SHT_NULL` is that it is mandatory for the first header table entry (index 0, named `SHN_UNDEF`), which is magic.

This is documented on the [System V ABI Update](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/2003-12-17/ch4.sheader.html) (recommended [by the LSB](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_4.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/normativerefs.html#STD.ABIUPDATE)):

> If the number of sections is greater than or equal to SHN_LORESERVE (0xff00), e_shnum has the value SHN_UNDEF (0) and the actual number of section header table entries is contained in the sh_size field of the section header at index 0 (otherwise, the sh_size member of the initial entry contains 0).

and:

> Other section type values are reserved. As mentioned before, the section header for index 0 (SHN_UNDEF) exists, even though the index marks undefined section references. This entry holds the following.

followed by a table that specifies what each entry of he section header means in that special case. In particular, `sh_type` must be `SHT_NULL`.

From the above, this first section seems to exist to allow a large number of sections to be encoded, but I haven't tested kernel and compiler support.