# Why do we use .globl main in MIPS assembly language?

Tags: assembly, mips, spim

```
       .text
.globl main
.ent   main
```

I don't know what `.globl` and `.ent` do.
What is the role?
Do I need to use `globl. main` and `.ent main` all the time?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your case, `.globl` is an assembler directive that tells the assembler that the `main` symbol will be accessible from outside the current file (that is, it can be referenced from other files), and `.ent` is a debugger (pseudo) operation that marks the entry of `main`.

Answer (score 5):

It is going to be the same in any other ISA on the GNU GAS assembler, e.g. on x86_64 Linux:

main.S

```
.text
.global _start
_start:
    /* exit syscall */
    mov $60, %rax
    mov exit_status, %rdi
    syscall
```

exit_status.S

```
.data
.global exit_status
exit_status:
    .quad 42
```

Assemble and run:

```
as -o main.o main.S
as -o exit_status.o exit_status.S
ls -o main.out exit_statis.o main.o
./main.out
echo $?
```

gives:

```
42
```

But if we remove the line:

```
.global exit_status
```

then `ld` fails with:

```
main.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0xb): undefined reference to `exit_status'
```

because it cannot see the symbol `exit_status` that it needs.

`.globl` and `.global` are synonyms as mentioned in the documentation: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Global.html#Global so I just prefer to use the one with the correct spelling ;-)

We can observe what is going on by looking into the information contained in the [ELF object files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294034/how-to-make-an-executable-elf-file-in-linux-using-a-hex-editor/30648229#30648229).

For the correct program:

```
nm hello_world.o mystring.o
```

gives:

```
main.o:
0000000000000000 T _start
                 U exit_status

exit_status.o:
0000000000000000 D exit_status
```

and for the failing one:

```
exit_status.o:
0000000000000000 d exit_status
```

And:

```
man nm
```

contains:

> The symbol type.  At least the following types are used; others are, as well, depending on the object file format.  If lowercase, the symbol is usually local; if uppercase, the symbol is global (external).  There are however a few lowercase symbols that are shown for special global symbols ("u", "v" and "w").
>
> ```
> "D"
> "d" The symbol is in the initialized data section.
>
> "T"
> "t" The symbol is in the text (code) section.
>
> "U" The symbol is undefined.
> ```

On the C level, you can control symbol visibility with the `static` keyword: [What does "static" mean in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572547/what-does-static-mean-in-c/14339047#14339047)

Tested in Ubuntu 16.04, Binutils 2.26.1.