# Modify asm instructions in an ELF binary

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, elf, hex-editors

I have the following ASM code from a simple obfuscated C program given to me as an assignment.

```
   0x00000000004006a0 <+147>:   lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
   0x00000000004006a4 <+151>:   mov    %rdx,%rsi
   0x00000000004006a7 <+154>:   mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x00000000004006aa <+157>:   callq  0x400713 <SECRET>   <======
   0x00000000004006af <+162>:   movl   $0x0,-0x24(%rbp)
   0x00000000004006b6 <+169>:   jmp    0x4006d8 <main+203>
   0x00000000004006b8 <+171>:   mov    -0x24(%rbp),%eax
```

The goal is find and remove a function (patch the program binary) that is causing a Segmentation Fault. I have found what function is causing the segfault, but I don't know how to patch the binary.

My problem is how to patch

```
 0x00000000004006aa <+157>:   callq  0x400713 <SECRET>
```

so that I wont call SECRET function.

If I use `gdb` to skip/jump SECRET by modifying the program counter while single-stepping at run-time, the program finishes execution and gives me the the output I want.

**What I want is a permanently-modified copy of the executable binary file that always skips without using a debugger.**

Comment: is there a way to skip it or jump that when i execute the program without gdb

Comment: Skipping over it in GDB doesn't count as solving your assignment, but yes, gdb can jump wherever you want.  Check the gdb manual.  You could even overwrite the `call` instruction with NOPs during that debugging session.  If this is something like a binary bomb-lab assignment, you're supposed to give it different input so execution never reaches that block.

Comment: Yes i can do that with program counter, however i am looking for a way to edit the binary and remove that function call and save the patched file.

Comment: Don't remove it, just overwrite the address.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez: If you overwrite the address but not the opcode, it will still CALL somewhere.  Much easier to NOP-out the whole call.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do it. for me it is the first time using GDB and I am still a bit lost in it. I am sorry

Comment: That's the idea, call anyway, but call where you want to.

Comment: GDB can't edit the permanent copy of the binary on disk.  Do you just want to modify the machine code in-memory for this run of the program?  Otherwise, this sounds like [an X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and you actually want a hex editor.  Post more of the exact wording of your assignment, because you're not making it clear what you're supposed to be doing.

Comment: I need to modify that line and overwrite the address so I will have a patch and save it. 

Is this somehow the right command to change the address:
set { unsigned char } 0 x804856f
= 0 x7f

Comment: Something like that could modify the in-memory image, but gdb won't help you much in creating a patch.  Do you literally need a binary patch?  Or is it ok to have a modified copy of the whole binary?  Either way, you should use a hex editor.  There are some that include an assembler / disassembler, so you can more easily find the asm instruction you want to patch.

Comment: I need to submit the modified copy of the whole binary. I downloaded GHex but it doesn't include an assembler. Is there a good one that I can use.

Comment: You don't actually *need* an editor that understands asm, you can just hex-edit the binary.  See this answer explaining what's what in an ELF executable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294034/how-to-make-an-executable-elf-file-in-linux-using-a-hex-editor/30648229#30648229.  Also, you should edit your question to ask about what you actually want to do, not the GDB false start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was curious on what else I can do with GDB. I managed to change the assembly with GDB and the patched program is working as it should.

I tried using nop but it didn't work then I looked to jump function. How my patch works is:

```
(gdb) set {unsigned char *}0x4006aa = 0xEB
(gdb) set {unsigned char *}0x4006ab = 0x0C
```

I am doing is a short jump.
Short jump opcode is EB XX where XX is the relative jump from the IP / PC.
So in this case I have to jump ahead 12 bytes, also the instruction is 2 bytes, so I write it in consecutive memory locations. I write the new modified binary to hard drive and everything great.

It took me a day of experimentation but at the end I learned a lot. :D

Comment: You could probably do `set {unsigned short *}0x4006aa = 0x0CEB` as well

Comment: Since it was the first time for me to do something like this I did it step by step.