# Create executable out of hexadecimal file under Linux

Tags: linux, compiler-construction, executable, machine-code, hexdump

I have a file which content represents x64 machine code in hex.

```
48 c7 c0 7b 00 00 00 48 c7 c1 59 01 00 00 48 01 c8 c3
```

The example above can be disassembled to:

```
0:  48 c7 c0 7b 00 00 00    mov    rax,0x7b
7:  48 c7 c1 59 01 00 00    mov    rcx,0x159
e:  48 01 c8                add    rax,rcx
11: c3                      ret
```

This machine code is being generated directly, so the assembler shown above is for the sake of the example. I do not have access to it in general.

What I want to do is convert this hex file to and executable in the most direct way possible. I tried using `xxd -r`, but this does not seem to create a well-formatted executable since I get a `Exec format error` when trying to run it.

How should I generate an executable from the hex code under Linux?

Comment: Essentially you want an elf binary? The most straightforward way would be to assemble the disassembled code you already have.

Comment: @PiRocks Seems like it yes! Although, I have a "compiler" which specifically does the job of the assembler, for that reason I do not want to depend on an external assembler. I guess my question is: now that I generated machine code, what is the last step to make it into an elf file?

Comment: The generated machine code does not need linking, it is guaranteed not to use external libraries.

Comment: So your looking for a programmatic way of creating an elf file instead of tool based approach? If so the two approaches are to generate an object file and use a linker to get a final elf file, or to generate the elf file yourself.

Comment: There's a header file called elf.h which defines the elf file format, which would be a starting point for a programmatic approach

Comment: Should I be able to do this using only, say, `ld` and `xxd`? From what I understand, I have my ELF data, I just need to create a header?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212453/discussion-between-pirocks-and-olivier-melancon).

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294034/how-to-make-an-executable-elf-file-in-linux-using-a-hex-editor  help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding of the discussion which followed my question, what I want to do is create an ELF file. This [question covers how to create your own ELF header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294034/how-to-make-an-executable-elf-file-in-linux-using-a-hex-editor).

Although, if you do not want to go through the trouble, you can actually use `gcc` to compile a sequence of bytes to an executable.

```
.section .text
    .global main
main:
    .byte 0x48 0xc7 0xc0 0x7b 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x48 0xc7 0xc1 0x59 0x01 ...
```

You can then compile the above with `gcc file.S -o file`. This will create the desired ELF file.