# undefined reference to Class::Function() C++

Tags: c++, codeblocks

After searching for a solution to this for about a half an hour I have made no progress. 
The errors are as follows:

s\My Workspace\Project\main.cpp  - Line 7 -  undefined reference to 'Sally::Sally()'

s\My Workspace\Project\main.cpp  - Line 9 - undefined reference to 'Sally::printCrap()'

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Sally.h"

int main()
{
    Sally sallyObject;
    sallyObject.printCrap();
}
```

Sally.h

```
#ifndef SALLY_H
#define SALLY_H


class Sally
{
    public:
        Sally();
        void printCrap();
};

#endif // SALLY_H
```

Sally.cpp

```
#include "Sally.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Sally::Sally(){
}

void Sally::printCrap(){
    cout << "Did someone say steak?" << endl;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The linker can't find definitions to the mentioned functions. Is your .cpp file included in the project you're using?

Comment: It looks like `Sally.cpp` is not part of the project that your are building.

Comment: please show us your command line for compiling and linking

Comment: How are you building this..? Makefile..? directly using gcc..?

Comment: @Tas how can i tell? The files are all under the same project in code::blocks

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a pretty old question but maybe it could help someone.

So, when adding any additional files (headers, source, etc.) follow this (if using Eclipse or similar IDE):

New file -> File... -> C/C++ header (source, etc.) -> next, next -> give it a name and make sure it's in the same path with your project, then check "Add file to active project", in build target(s): check all -> Finish.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your linker doesn't find Sally.cpp. ([Quick intro to linker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322911/what-do-linkers-do))

To compile your code type:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp Sally.cpp
```