# How do the preprocessor's and linker's jobs not interfere?

Tags: c, linker, c-preprocessor

As far as I understand:

- **[Preprocessor's job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)**:

> provides the ability for the inclusion of header files, macro expansions, conditional compilation, and line control.

The one I'm concerned with is the *inclusion of header files*, it does so by replacing `#include blabla.h` with the actual code of `blabla.h`. And it is invoked ***before compiling***.

- **[Linker's job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing))**:

> takes one or more object files generated by a compiler and combines them into a single executable file, library file, or another object file.

Reading many [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322911/what-do-linkers-do) here on StackOverflow, I understood that it "links" the other libraries whose functions I may be using in my code with my actual code, e.g., `stdio.h` and `printf();`. And it is invoked **after compiling**.

Now my question is, if the preprocessor has already --literally-- included that library's code in my code, why do we need linking? Assuming they've become one file.

Comment: The preprocessor doesn't include any library code. It just includes the _header files_ which are not the same thing as _library code_.

Comment: Care to elaborate the difference, please?

Comment: Very basically: The header files contain only _declarations_. For example the declaration of the `printf` function in the `<stdio.h>` header file just declares that a function named `printf` exists.  But the actual _code_ of the `printf` function is not in that header file. That code is linked to _your _ code by the linker.

Comment: I see, sorry for my ignorance. Thank you.