# How do I avoid the "multiple definition of ..." Error in this case

Tags: c++, class, redefinition, platformio

Boardcomputer.h:

```
#ifndef BOARDCOMPUTER_H
#define BOARDCOMPUTER_H

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <TFT_eSPI.h>

TFT_eSPI disp = TFT_eSPI();

...

#endif
```

Boardcomputer.cpp:

```
#include <Boardcomputer.h>

^^use disp functions^^
...
```

Error:

```
.pio\build\EmmaChip\lib782\libBoardcomputer.a(Boardcomputer.cpp.o):(.bss.disp+0x0): multiple definition of `disp'
.pio\build\EmmaChip\src\main.cpp.o:(.bss.disp+0x0): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** [.pio\build\EmmaChip\firmware.elf] Error 1
```

### Here is what I tried:

- make an extra Header-File and add `#pragma once` at the top
- make an extra Lib and add the typical `#ifndef; #define; #endif` lines

Do you have some ideas to fix this problem?
I don't define 'disp' multiple times. Just in one Header.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243406/discussion-on-question-by-levi-how-do-i-avoid-the-multiple-definition-of-e).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
#ifndef BOARDCOMPUTER_H
#define BOARDCOMPUTER_H

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <TFT_eSPI.h>

TFT_eSPI disp = TFT_eSPI();    
...    
#endif
```

You define `disp` in a header file. Defining variables in header files is plain wrong, it cannot work (except if you include the .h file in a single .c file, but then the .h file is pretty pointless anyway) and it leads to these "multiple definition" issues at link time.

This happens here:

- you include `Boardcomputer.h` in `foo.c`, therefore `foo.o` will contain a variable `disp`. The code compile fine.
- you include `Boardcomputer.h` in `bar.c`, therefore `bar.o` will contain a variable `disp`. The code compile fine.
- you link `foo.o` and `bar.o` in order to produce an executable, and the linker sees two variables `disp`, one in `bar.o` and one in `foo.o`, hence the *multiple definition* error

---

You want this:

Boardcomputer.h

```
#ifndef BOARDCOMPUTER_H
#define BOARDCOMPUTER_H

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <TFT_eSPI.h>

extern TFT_eSPI disp;     // declare it here
    
#endif
```

Boardcomputer.c

```
#include "Boardcomputer.h"
...
TFT_eSPI disp = TFT_eSPI();   // define it here
...
```

Comment: I still don't understand why the linker complains. Shouldn't the header guards make sure that there is only one global "disp" defined? If `foo.c` includes `Boardcomputer.h` then `bar.c` won't include it because of the header guard. Hence, the shouldn't be a second definition of "disp". What's the mistake in my thoughts here?

Comment: @Joerg no, the linker has no knowledge of header guards at all. Your favorite C text book should explain the process of compiling and linking. You can also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322911/what-do-linkers-do

Comment: I've just read this: "Note that the goal of header guards is to prevent a code file from receiving more than one copy of a guarded header. By design, header guards do not prevent a given header file from being included (once) into separate code files." in https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/header-guards/ Maybe it helps others too who have become a bit rusty in their C++.