"Undefinded reference" for functions in my code. Why my compiler can't find it?
I'm writing a program for my C programming classess and my profesor didn't really explain to us how to make functions and "import" them to our main file. I'm keep getting error with undefined reference.
main.c
#include "vect.h"

int main(void)
{
  vector_t vector_1 = vectorInit(5, 10);
  vector_t vector_2 = vectorInit(5, 10);

  vectorPrint(vector_1);
  vectorPrint(vector_2);

  return 0;
}

vect.h
#ifndef VECT_H_
#define VECT_H_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct vectorType {
  int32_t *buffer;
  uint16_t length;
} vector_t;

uint16_t FillArray32MinMax(int32_t *array, int32_t min, int32_t max, uint16_t limit);

uint16_t GetArray32MinMax(int32_t **array, int32_t min, int32_t max);

bool vectorIsSet(vector_t vector);

void vectorPrint(vector_t vector);

vector_t vectorInit(int32_t min, int32_t max);

#endif

vect.c
#include "vect.h"

uint16_t FillArray32MinMax(int32_t *array, int32_t min, int32_t max, uint16_t limit)
{
  uint16_t i = 0;
  while(min != max) {
    if(max > min) array[i++] = min++;
    else array[i++] = min--;
    if(!--limit) return 0;
  };
  array[i++] = min;
  return i;
}

uint16_t GetArray32MinMax(int32_t **array, int32_t min, int32_t max)
{
  uint16_t length;
  if(max > min) length = (uint16_t)(max - min + 1);
  else length = (uint16_t)(min - max + 1);

  *array = (int32_t *)malloc(length * sizeof(int32_t));
  return FillArray32MinMax(*array, min, max, length);
}

vector_t vectorInit(int32_t min, int32_t max)
{
  vector_t vector;
  vector.length = GetArray32MinMax(&vector.buffer, min, max);
  return vector;
}

bool vectorIsSet(vector_t vector)
{
  if(vector.length) return true;
  else false;
}

void vectorPrint(vector_t vector)
{
  for (uint16_t i = 0; i < vector.length; i++)
    printf("%d ", vector.buffer[i]);
  printf("\n");
}

I'm trying to understand what's the issue here. VS Code doesn't give me launch.json file to analize. All I see is "undefined reference to `vectorInit'" for this and other functions.
I tried to search in other forums, but didn't find any solutions.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322911/what-do-linkers-do
