# How to tell if some process is x86, x64, ARM64 or ARM64EC by its PID?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, arm64

I know that there's `IsWow64Process` for determining 32-bit vs 64-bit and also newer `IsWow64Process2` which seemed like a solution but it doesn't work for determining what I stated in the title.

Is there a documented API to do that?

PS. All I can think of at the moment is reading the target process PE header (via its virtual memory read) and checking the `IMAGE_FILE_HEADER.Machine` in it.

Comment: I don't think there is a single API for this. IsWow64Process2() is the closest but only gets you some of the way there. I don't recall off the top of my head but there might be a NtQueryInformationProcess() parameter or PEB field that will give you the process architecture; otherwise reading from the PE header should work in all cases.

Comment: @Luke i understand that. It's just too many steps for such a simple operation, thus I thought that they have a ready-made API for that. I didn't know that no one has any idea how to do it. I need to RE task manager to see how MSFT does it.

Comment: Looks like [on Windows 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-process_machine_information) taskmgr.exe does `GetProcessInformation(ProcessMachineTypeInfo)`. Otherwise it reads something from the PEB.

Comment: Depend on your diecription, You can open the target process with `OpenProcess`. Then use the Ntddl.dll import table to get the target process information by using Microsoft's undisclosed functions `NtWow64QueryInformationProcess64`(`NtQueryInformationProcess`) and `NtWow64ReadVirtualMemory64`(`ReadProcessMemory`). This may help: https://gist.github.com/Torrecto/e9486a79ba448a9cb29632ccfcddbd98  Current process only can run in x86.

Comment: Note that IMAGE_FILE_HEADER.Machine is virtualized in EC or miXed processes and will not represent truth. I have learned that the hard way.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [`IsWow64Process2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wow64apiset/nf-wow64apiset-iswow64process2) requires a `HANDLE hProcess`. So the question becomes [how to get a process handle from a pid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221103/how-to-get-process-handle-from-process-id).

[OpenProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess)

```
HANDLE OpenProcess(
  [in] DWORD dwDesiredAccess,
  [in] BOOL  bInheritHandle,
  [in] DWORD dwProcessId
);
```

Comment: This is not what I'm asking.

Comment: Yes, actually it is. Given only a PID, you can open a `HANDLE` to the process, and then query that process for its architecture.  Did you see the [link I gave you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184137/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-process-is-32-or-64-bit/14186661#comment136942232_14186661) earlier on another question regarding this same topic?

Comment: @c00000fd Caution: Minimum supported client of `IsWow64Process2` is Windows 10, version 1709. Minimum supported server is Windows Server 2016, version 1709.