# Detecting 32/64 -bit Java from within C on windows

Tags: java, c, windows

I would like to find out if the Java runtime installed on a user's machine supports 32 and 64-bit, and I would like to do this from within C. I had thought that something like the following would do the trick:

Detect 64-bit java:

```
int f=0
char *path = (char*) malloc(32768);
char out[1035]; 
FILE *fp;
if(f) fprintf(f,"Checking if 64-bit Java is available via the java command\n");
java64ok = 1;
strcpy(path,"java -d64 -version 2>&1");
fp = _popen(path, "r");
if (fp == NULL) {
    if(f) fprintf(f,"Failed to run command\n" );
}
if(fgets(out, sizeof(out), fp) != NULL){
    if(strncmp(out,"Error",5)==0){
        java64ok = 0;
    }
    while (fgets(out, sizeof(out), fp) != NULL) {}
}
if (feof(fp)){
    pclose( fp );
}
else{
    if(f) fprintf(f, "Error: Failed to read the pipe to the end.\n");
}
```

Detect 32-bit Java:

```
if(f) fprintf(f,"Checking if 32-bit Java is available via the java command\n");
java32ok = 1;
strcpy(path,"java -d32 -version 2>&1");
fp = _popen(path, "r");
if (fp == NULL) {
    if(f) fprintf(f,"Failed to run command\n" );
}
if(fgets(out, sizeof(out), fp) != NULL){
    if(strncmp(out,"Error",5)==0){
        java32ok = 0;
    }
    while (fgets(out, sizeof(out), fp) != NULL) {}
}
if (feof(fp)){
    pclose( fp );
}
else{
    if(f) fprintf(f, "Error: Failed to read the pipe to the end.\n");
}
```

Unfortunately, this appears that if the user is running a 64-bit system only the 32 bit java is detected if the C code is compiled as a 32 bit executable, and only the 64-bit Java is detected if the program is compiled as a 64-bit program.

Comment: The `-d32` and `-d64` options only work on Solaris.

Comment: They work fine for me with Oracle Java on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

With reasonable reliability, you can check %SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64\java.exe (which is where 32 bit java.exe resides on a 64 bit machine), and %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\java.exe (which is where 64 bit java resides on a 64 bit machine and also where 32 bit java resides on a 32 bit machine.)

Use the Windows API function GetEnvironmentVariable to deduce %SYSTEMROOT%, or, to get started, hardcode to "C:\Windows", escaping \ as necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This looks promising. Any idea how "reasonably reliable" this approach is? Are these locations always present in Oracle Java installs?

Comment: Personally I think it's robust. Oracle puts the executables in these directories do you can call java from anywhere without messing about with your machine path.

Comment: @IanFellows Java can be installed anywhere on your system.

Answer (score 0):

How you detect the version externally is platform dependant.  I sugges you run a short Java program to tell you.

```
public class Bitness {
    public static void main(String... ignored) {
        System.out.println(is64Bit() ? "64" : "32");
    }

    private static boolean is64Bit0() {
        String systemProp;
        systemProp = System.getProperty("com.ibm.vm.bitmode");
        if (systemProp != null) {
            return "64".equals(systemProp);
        }
        systemProp = System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model");
        if (systemProp != null) {
            return "64".equals(systemProp);
        }
        systemProp = System.getProperty("java.vm.version");
        return systemProp != null && systemProp.contains("_64");
    }
}
```

This way you can run `java -cp {whatever} Bitness` and it will tell you.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Java 64 and 32 may both be installed and this only detects the architecture of whatever java you call. I specifically wish to know which architectures are supported by Java from a windows 32 application written in C.

Comment: @IanFellows You can run any version which is installed.  You have to find/know where they are installed, but once you have that you need to determine their bit-ness.  What can I add to the answer?

Comment: Apparently not. The code in the question is only able to run java with the same bit-ness as the compiled C code.

Comment: Can you confirm you can run a 64-bit C program from this application?  This doesn't appear to be a problem in Java code.

Answer (score 0):

the suggestion of Bathsheba is quite solid, though depending on how the PATH variable is defined on a system, it might be possible that another java.exe binary is found before %SYSTEMROOT%\, so there is a chance that a different java version is used.

My suggestion would be to first parse PATH environment variable and find the first hit for java. Second step would be to look at the COFF header of the java.exe file.
With the [ImageNtHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, you can query the NT header and this contains the field **FileHeader**, which is a [IMAGE_FILE_HEADER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680313%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Here's some example on how you would implement this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4316804/435583

Hope this helps you out.
Cheers