# GNU as: getting section start & end addresses

Tags: assembly, mips, gnu

I'm porting a MIPS assembler program (non-MIPSPro compatible syntax) that uses `sect()` and `sectend()` functions. Looks like they return the start and end addresses of the section. Seems GNU AS docs does not supports anything similar - any ideas how to 
code this in GAS syntax?

Here are some examples.

```
        la  t0,sect(.bss)
        la  t1,sectend(.bss)
    @clear:
        sw  zero,0(t0)
        addiu   t0,t0,4
        sltu    at,t0,t1
        bne at,zero,@clear
        nop

....

__text  dw  sect(.text)
__textlen   dw  sectend(.text)-sect(.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may found your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370407/get-the-start-and-end-address-of-text-section-in-an-executable) and [here](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/PROVIDE.html) if you are using a system that run ELF executables.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you put the information (wrap the section with indicators that you can read as variables in the asm) in the linker script.  That is how I have seen the .data section get copied from flash to ram, and .bss get zeroed...(using gnu tools).