# Linux elf .text direction

Tags: c++, c, linux, elf

I want to know to the .text start and size of my c++ application. I have been reading related topics about this ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370407/get-the-start-and-end-address-of-text-section-in-an-executable)) but I am not able to do what I want.

Analyzing readelf output of my sample program I got this:

```
Section Headers:
[Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align

[14] .text             PROGBITS         0000000000400830  00000830
0000000000000252  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     16
```

So I understand that .text section of my program start at 0x400830 address.

But I cant access to this address from my program:

```
printf("My process ID : %d\n", getpid());
printf("Executable Start address: 0x%lx\n", (unsigned long)&__executable_start);
printf("Text Start Address: 0x%lx\n", (unsigned long)&__etext);
```

But the output is:

```
My process ID : 4029
Executable Start address: 0x400000
Text Start Address: 0x400a8d
```

As you can see the start address is not the same. How I can access the start address of the .text section. I need to know the size or the end address... It this possible?

Comment: __etext is the end of the text section, the "e" kinda hints you about that.

Comment: C != C++. Tag only with the language that you're using, unless both are actually relevant.

Comment: and if __etext is the end of the text section... how i can get the start of the text section?

Comment: Also depending on what you're trying to achieve, ALSR might be a serious PITA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know to the .text start and size of my c++ application.

If you told us *why* you want to know that, you would likely have gotten a better answer.

Note that an executable *doesn't* need to have a `.text` section *at all*: section table may be stripped, and the executable will still run just fine. For such a binary, your question is not answerable.

To know the exact offset and size of `.text` for an ELF binary, one simply has to read the section table (just as `readelf` does). It's [not hard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10865542/50617).

Without doing that, you can get quite close by using heuristics / approximations.

You've already found `__executable_start` and `__etext`. A tighter bound could be obtained by using `&__start` -- *usually* that is the very first symbol in the `.text` section.