# What is the difference between Entry point address and __executable_start

Tags: c, linux, elf, objdump, readelf

I'm learning how a linker works on Linux. I'm told that a linker will generate some symbols for an executable file, such as `__executable_start`, which is the address where the program starts.

Also, I've known that there was a "Entry point address" in the ELF file.

So I don't know what the difference between them is.

I wrote a simple code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern char __executable_start[];

int main()
{
    printf("Executable Start %X\n", __executable_start);

    return 0;
}
```

I compile it with GCC and get an executable file named `a.out`.

When I execute it, it gives me `Executable Start 4CEDA000`.

Then I execute the command `readelf -h a.out` and the output about the Entry point is `Entry point address: 0x540`

Well, obviously, `0x540` and `4CEDA000` are totally different.

Comment: [__executable_start is the start of the code section (called .text for some reason)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370407/get-the-start-and-end-address-of-text-section-in-an-executable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol `__executable_start` is not the entry point, but the beginning of the `.text` section. The symbol `_start_` is indeed the entry point.

In your case, the symbol `_start` is located at `4CEDA540` at runtime. This is, because the binary can be loaded at some random place for security reasons (PIE), so the entry point is only stored relative to the offset of the (randomly located at runtime by ASLR) `.text` section in the binary. This is, why only `540` is shown by *readelf*.